# cannot read file.properties from resource file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classloader, inputstream, fileinputstream

I created a jar file which use a Meta-Inf/config.properties file!!
the problem is that I would like to use Meta-Inf/config.properties from resource file and not from jar file
I tried this

```
InputStream input =  classLoader.getResourceAsStream("META-INF/config.properties");
```

but this line read the config.properties file from jar and not from resource file!!
I tried also something like:

```
InputStream input =  classLoader.getResourceAsStream("classpath:META-INF/config.properties");
```

but nothing
any idea

- resource file: is only the directory src/main/resources

Answer (score 0):

Ways of Accessing resources :

```
String pathToPropertyFile = "resources/META-INF/config.properties";
InputStream stream= ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream(pathToImage );
```

Or

```
   String pathToPropertyFile = "resources/META-INF/config.properties";
   InputStream stream= ClassName.class.getResource(pathToImage );
```

Assuming there is a folder by the name of `META-INF` under `scr/main/resources/`